# CSS text layout HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css, layout, text

I can't find anything about this, maybe some of you can help me with this one.

How do i make the layout of the text like this on the picture 
[image]

The html code would be like this

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="">Number 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Number 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Number 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Number 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Number 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Number 6</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Number 7</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Number 8</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Number 9</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Number 10</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Number 11</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Number 12</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Number 13</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Number 14</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Number 15</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Number 16</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Number 17</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Number 18</a></li>
</ul>
```

I hope that someone know how this is done.

Thanks.

Comment: bootstrapping it would be one way

Comment: Possible to modify the HTML?

Comment: You can use `table` to do that, sorry @Fred but I don't like bootstrappers.

Comment: Thanks, i'll look into that :) just what i needed @nmnsud

Comment: @nmnsud *"but I don't like bootstrappers"* - then you're saying you don't like me; how lovely. I think that kind of opinion can best be kept to yourself. The OP has a choice, mine isn't "bad" just because "you" don't like it.

Comment: Like Fred-ii said you can use bootstrap. It helps a lot in layout of HTML

Comment: heck, you can even do this in php, but that may be too complex (for you). There are many many ways to do this really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't think of a pure CSS solution. However if you want to retain the HTML structure, you could use a simple JavaScript/jQuery solution to contain every 3 items in a floated block:

```js
var items_per_col = 3;
var items = $('.reorder').children();
for ( var i = 0; i < items.length; i+= items_per_col) {
  items.slice(i, i + items_per_col).wrapAll("<div class='block'></div>");
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border:1px solid red;
}

.reorder {
  overflow: auto;
  max-width: 230px;
}

.reorder .block {
  border:1px solid black;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="reorder">
    <li><a href="#">Number 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Number 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Number 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Number 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Number 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Number 6</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Number 7</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Number 8</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Number 9</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Number 10</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Number 11</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Number 12</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Number 13</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Number 14</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Number 15</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Number 16</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Number 17</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Number 18</a></li>
</ul>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/9qh23top/

Answer (score 1):

How about dividing the list into two parts and using column property of CSS.

**HTML**:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Number 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Number 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Number 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Number 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Number 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Number 6</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Number 7</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Number 8</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Number 9</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Number 10</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Number 11</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Number 12</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>

  <li><a href="">Number 13</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Number 14</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Number 15</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Number 16</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Number 17</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Number 18</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**:

```
ul {
  column-count: 3
}
```

Learn more about CSS columns here:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns/Using_multi-column_layouts